# Sorting a filter in descending order using query builder

Tags: asp.net, linq, sorting, filter

I am new to ASP.NET, and I am trying to sort my filter code by descending order.

This is what I did, but still encountering issues.  I would please like to know where "order by DateChanged desc" should be inserted to prevent an error.

```
public static List<string> FilterByProgress(this List<string> whereQueryBuilder, string[] progress)
{
    if (progress.Length > 0)
    {
        whereQueryBuilder.Add(string.Format("TA.Progress  IN ({0} order by DateChanged desc)",
             string.Join(",", progress.Select(n => "'" + n.ToString() + "'").ToArray())));
    }

    return whereQueryBuilder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Order By` should be seen as a separate clause, distinct from the `Where` part of the SQL statement.  You just need to move the end parentheses and make it like this:

```
"TA.Progress  IN ({0}) order by DateChanged desc"
```